# Why does ruby modules gave me NoMethod error?

Tags: ruby, module

this is my project tree

- project

  - main.rb
  - lib

    - some_module.rb

main.rb:

```
$LOAD_PATH<<'./lib'
require 'some_module'
SomeModule::some_func 'p1', 'p2'
```

some_module.rb

```
module SomeModule
  def some_func p1,p2
    puts p1,p2
  end
end
```

but when i run main.rb.
ruby gave me a NoMethodError, why?

Comment: Please show how do you define `some_func` in `SomeModule`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call the method on the base module which is why you get the error.  If you were including this module inside of a class, this method would only be available as an instance method.  Since you can't define an instance of the module, you need to define it like this, and you can call it directly on the module.

```
module SomeModule
  def self.some_func p1,p2
    puts p1,p2
  end
end
```

However if you wanted to make this an instance method you could do this:

```
#main.rb
$LOAD_PATH<<'./lib'
require 'some_module'

class Foo
  include SomeModule
end

@foo = Foo.new

@foo.some_func 'p1', 'p2'

#lib/some_module.rb
module SomeModule
  def some_func p1,p2
    puts p1,p2
  end
end
```

Comment: but i'm not using it in a class

Comment: right I was just explaining that if you were, then you'd define it as you had previously.  Take what you need from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `some_func` as an instance method of `SomeModule`:

> ```
> module SomeModule
>   def some_func p1,p2
>     puts p1,p2
>   end
> end
> ```

But you are calling it on `SomeModule`. Since `SomeModule` is not an instance of `SomeModule` (it is an instance of `Module`), you get a `NoMethodError`:

> ```
> SomeModule::some_func 'p1', 'p2'
> ```

So, you either need to construct an instance of `SomeModule`:

```
(foo = Object.new).extend(SomeModule)
foo.some_func(:p1, :p2)
```

Or you need to ensure that you define `some_func` somewhere `SomeModule` is an instance of, such as `SomeModule`'s singleton class (every object in Ruby is an instance of its singleton class, actually the only instance):

```
module SomeModule
  def self.some_func(p1, p2)
    puts p1, p2
  end
end
```